# Fetch JSON object is undefined

Tags: javascript, json

When a user add the markers on the Google Map, I'm saving it as a JSON string on my MySQL database like this:

```
    [{"k":52.908902047770255,"D":-3.427734375},{"k":56.31653672211301,"D":7.03125}]
```

"k" is the latitude and "B" the longitude of the added marker.

I also save the polylines between the markers like this:

```
 [[52.908902047770255,-3.427734375],[56.31653672211301,7.03125]]
```

I have a function witch fetch all the markers and polylines from the database, to display it back to the screen, here is my query:

```
 function getMarkersByTripId($tripId)
 {
   if ($bdd = mysqli_connect(_BDD_HOST_, _BDD_USERNAME_, _BDD_PASSWORD_, _BDD_NAME_)) {

     $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT `markers`, `polylines` FROM `trip` WHERE `trip_id` = "'.$tripId.'"';
    $req = mysqli_query($bdd, $sql);

    if ($req) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($req)) {
            $jsonData= array('markers'=>$row[0], 'polylines'=>$row[1]);
        }
        echo json_encode($jsonData);
    }

     else {
         echo json_encode(array('status' => 'failure'));
     }
   }

     if ($bdd) {
        mysqli_close($bdd);
   }
}
```

a var_dump of $jsonData looks like this:

```
 array(2) {
            ["markers"]=>
            string(79) "[{"k":52.908902047770255,"D":-3.427734375},{"k":56.31653672211301,"D":7.03125}]"
            ["polylines"]=>
             string(63) "[[52.908902047770255,-3.427734375],[56.31653672211301,7.03125]]"
 }
```

In my JavaScript, when I'm doing:

```
 console.log(jsonText);
```

It's formed like:

```
 "{"markers":"[{\"k\":52.908902047770255,\"D\":-3.427734375},{\"k\":56.31653672211301,\"D\":7.03125}]","polylines":"[[52.908902047770255,-3.427734375],[56.31653672211301,7.03125]]"}"
```

As you can see, it's a simple string containing the JSON result returned by the function getMarkerByTripId() function. Now, I want to convert my JSON string to an object like this:

```
 var jsonData =  JSON.parse(jsonText);  
 console.log(jsonData);
```

It seems working and it display something like:

```
 Object { markers: "[{"k":52.908902047770255,"D":-3.427734375},{"k":56.31653672211301,"D":7.03125}]", polylines: "[[52.908902047770255,-3.427734375],[56.31653672211301,7.03125]]" }
```

The problem is: I can't access to the latitude/longitude (k/D JSON elements), it's always undefined, here is how I'm doing it after the JSON.parse(jsontext):

```
   console.log(jsonData['markers'].k);
```

It always return "undefined" and in order to add the marker on the Google map, I need to know what I'm doing wrong with the JSON parsing. The rest is OK, I know how to loop through my JSON object to add the markers and the polylines on the map automatically.

I was thinking that when I'm fetching the JSON string from MySQL database, it may add double quote, witch can defect the JSON parsing. Thank you very much if someone can guide me to the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jsonData.markers` is double `json` encoded you will first `parse` `jsonData.markers` key object

```
var jsonText = {
  "markers": "[{\"k\":52.908902047770255,\"D\":-3.427734375},{\"k\":56.31653672211301,\"D\":7.03125}]",
  "polylines": "[[52.908902047770255,-3.427734375],[56.31653672211301,7.03125]]"
};


var markers = JSON.parse(jsonText.markers);
var polylines = JSON.parse(jsonText.polylines);
console.log('markers  ', markers, ' polylines', polylines);
```

In php code: warp `markers`, `polylines` with `json_decode()` function in while loop,  because both values are already json string, and when you use again `json_encode` these double encode.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($req)) {
  $jsonData= array(
       'markers'=>json_decode($row[0]), 
       'polylines'=>json_decode($row[1])
  );
}
```

UPDATE PHP CODE

```
<?php
$arr1 = array(
 "markers" => '[{"k":52.908902047770255,"D":-3.427734375},{"k":56.31653672211301,"D":7.03125}]',
 "polylines" =>'[[52.908902047770255,-3.427734375],[56.31653672211301,7.03125]]'
);

echo "//your problem \n";
echo json_encode($arr1);

$arr2 = array(
 "markers" => json_decode('[{"k":52.908902047770255,"D":-3.427734375},{"k":56.31653672211301,"D":7.03125}]'),
 "polylines" =>json_decode('[[52.908902047770255,-3.427734375],[56.31653672211301,7.03125]]')
);


echo "\n\n//my solution\n";
echo json_encode($arr2);

//after solution markers, polylines keys wrapped with one more array so you will need to use `[0]` index in javascript
// jsonText.markers[0].k;   jsonText.markers[0].d etc

// you can also do

$arr3 = array(
 "markers" => array_shift(json_decode('[{"k":52.908902047770255,"D":-3.427734375},{"k":56.31653672211301,"D":7.03125}]')),
 "polylines" =>array_shift(json_decode('[[52.908902047770255,-3.427734375],[56.31653672211301,7.03125]]'))
);


echo "\n\n//another one more solution my solution\n";
echo json_encode($arr3);

//now you can access values in JavaScript
// jsonText.markers.k;   jsonText.markers.d etc

?>
```

---

[see more detail click here](https://eval.in/233991)

Comment: Still undefined, I don't understand why your doing: jsonText.markers ? jsonText is a string witch represent my JSON object. Even if I use jsonData.markers it create this error:  JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: @Katcha see updated answer, i have also added solution for php script

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your JavaScript with the hard-coded jsonText works fine but when I'm replacing it by the JSON object returned by the PHP function it doesn't work anymore, it says: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data. Here is the presentation of my JSON returned by the PHP function: "{"markers":[{"k":52.90890204777,"D":-3.427734375},{"k":56.316536722113,"D":7.03125}],"polylines":[[52.90890204777,-3.427734375],[56.316536722113,7.03125]]}"

Comment: if you will be make change in php code according php code in my answer then simple `JSON.parse(jsonText);` would be work

Comment: I made those changes on the PHP side as well. I don't know if you tested it, but it doesn't work. Here is the modification, if you want to check: http://pastie.org/private/g2bz3zk6h8e1tpjrz00zw

Comment: I think I found the problem! If I console.log(jsonText), it looks like this = "{"markers":[{"k":52.90890204777,"D":-3.427734375},{"k":56.316536722113,"D":7.03125}],"polylines":[[52.90890204777,-3.427734375],[56.316536722113,7.03125]]}" As you can see, there's double quote witch wrap the JSON description and break the JSON.parse(). How to get rid of those double quote from PHP MySQL?

Comment: But I'm not sure, maybe those double quote are just displayed from console.log by default ...

Comment: @Katcha see this link https://eval.in/233991 and also in answer in update section, hope you will understand now.. whats problem in code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66752/discussion-between-girish-and-katcha).

Answer (score 0):

The member 'markers' is an array, you must specify from which element you need the coordinates in this array.
Try this for accessing the first one to check if it works :

```
console.log(jsonData['markers'][0].k);
```

Comment: It still gives me "undefined". I edited my post to show you how my result from MySQL looks like.

Comment: If your console logs properly what's in your object, it de facto means that these elements are defined at the moment you are printing them. Are you sure you are not trying to access your members somehow before they get parsed ?

Comment: If you check the Javascript above of Girish, it works fine. There's something wrong with the PHP function witch may returns a malformed JSON object, but can't see it yet.

Comment: Have you tried other json_encode flags, for example second arguments like JSON_FORCE_OBJECT to see if it change something ?

Comment: Nothing to do with this JSON flag, the problem is my JSON object returned by php/MySQL wrap the JSON string with double quote and it breaks the JSON.parse() on the JavaScript side. Do you know how to clean my JSON string to parse it properly?